# BLAS+Multiple Precision+MPI

Tags: c++

I am writing a scientific application for my Maths PhD in C++, it's based on some heavy linear algebra, mostly BLAS level 3 routines. The sizes of the matrices employed vary considerably, ideally I would like to be able to deal with very large matrices of order 10000 and higher. So far I have used Intel MKL, multi-threaded, scales nicely onto 8 cores. My algorithm produces the correct results, however is very unstable, in double precision arithmetic, due to the accumulating errors, resulting from high powers being taken. Additionally, as I have access to a large supercomputer cluster, and my algorithm can be easily scaled across multiple nodes, I would like to employ MPI to scale the application across hundreds of nodes.

My goal is to find a templated BLAS library that:

Supports Multiple Precision Arithmetic,
Supports Multi-threading,
Supports MPI

My findings so far:
MTL4 - Matrix Template library 4 seems to do all of the above, however the open source edition will only run on one core, and the supercomputing edition is quite costly.

Eigen - appears not to support multicore? Does it support multicore and MPI if linked with MKL?

Armadillo - does all the above?

I would greatly appreciate any insights and recommendations

Kind Regards,

Maria

Comment: If you're sure that MTL4 satisfies your needs perfectly I would recommend to contact MTL4 sales directly and ask for a single free education license.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your matrix problem, the [Tpetra package of Trilinos](http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/tpetra/) might be worth a look. It's templated on the scalar type, so you might use multiple precision types. It targets large scale applications on supercomputers so one can expect good parallel performances.

Hope it helps!

Edit: and it's free!